# When exactly does dependencyManagement take precedence over versions in dependency definitions?

Tags: maven, dependency-management

Suppose I define the version of some artifact in my dependencyManagement section.

Is it correct that this version definition overwrites all version definitions in *transitive* dependencies?

Or does it only solve version conflicts?

So if I put foo in version 2.0.0 in my dependencyManagement and some transitive dependency has foo in version 1.0.0, do I always get 2.0.0?

Answer (score 0):

That is how it would work with Maven 2. And generally speaking that's the basic rule: whatever your project specifies takes precedence over whatever your dependencies specify.

However, according to [Maven 3.x Compatibility Notes](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Maven+3.x+Compatibility+Notes), this process was changed in Maven 3. Now  it uses [Aether](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Aether/What_Is_Aether) and is supposed to be smarter and possibly even take semantic versioning into consideration even when [version ranges](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/versionRanges.html) are not used. In my opinion, the documentation is spread out and not very clear. I think the main difference, though, is how conflicts are resolved between two dependencies, not between your project and dependency. So the first rule should still apply.